# Asset isn't precompiled after upload with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm using the carrierwave gem to upload file attachments to Google cloud storage. This works great on development environment, but on production environment after uploading an attachemnt, I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (attachment.gif isn't precompiled):
```

It seems Rails needs all it's assets precompiled, is there a way to exclude the file uploads done by my website visitors? Probably a setting in the production config file?

Comment: Already solved it, I changed the CarrierWave cache directory to the "tmp" folder, so Rails won't complain about precompiling assets in the "public" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, I changed the carrierwave cache folder.